# Google Play services and WebView strange interaction

Tags: android, webview, google-play-services

I have an app which uses Vision API from Google, and has a WebView which shows some internet content.
When the build.gradle file contains this line:

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8+'
>   everything compiles and work ok.

I want to use the latest version, so I change it to:

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'

Then I hit the limit of 64K method references in a .dex file
Using multidex library and changing my manifest file, doesn't solve it.

So I tried the granular approach, and changed the line to:

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.6.1'

Then it compiles ok, but when running, every attempt to load a url in WebView,
fails and onReceivedError is called with errorCode -1.

I don't know if it is important, but the actual use of WebView, is done from a library which has nothing to do with Play Services.

Can somebody propose something?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then I hit the limit of 64K method references in a .dex file

Because it contains more than `56k` methods.

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.6.1` is for  Mobile Vision.

I can help you with getting over the 64 method limit though, do the steps below

But first make sure you have permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and active internet connection.

First put this in your `buidl.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

then put `multiDexEnabled true`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

}
```

Then go to your menifest and in your application tag

```
<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
```

I hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: I have already done these steps and didn't help, as I said in my question

Comment: I will accept your answer, since the problem was the missing permission! With the granular approach I don't even need the multidex. But how was it loading the urls with play services version 8, and didn't have this problem earlier?

Comment: internet permission part was bit buggy on older API, it allowed the connection most of time without permissions . Once i was building the app and it had ads in it and after the release I found that there is no permission added for internet and ads were working fine